# Why Context.Consumer is blocking UI?

Tags: react-native, styles, expo, react-native-router-flux

Why is Context.Consumer blocking the UI? I see it has styles like:

```
position: absolute
left: 0
right: 0
top: 0
bottom: 0
```

But none of my code has those properties.

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: Hi NingaCodingTRV,

Please post the relevant minimal reproducible example code in your question, don’t post it somewhere else on the internet; make it easy for people to help you and you’ll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/7515189

Comment: i literally don't know, where comes that layout, i can't add reproducible test.

Comment: You can see in the image, the layout tree. looks like it's a tree of views generated by "react-native-router-flux" or something in a React Component (because Context.Consumer) that i don't handle.